# serialize array of objects using Doctrine and JMSSerializer annotations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle, jms-serializer

I have a model

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="polygon")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\PolygonRepository")
     * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("none")
     */
    class Polygon {
         /**
          * @var string
          *
          * @ORM\Column(name="polygon", type="json_array")
          * @JMS\Type("array<MyBundle\Model\Point>")
          */
          private $points;

          /***/
    }
```

in DB it's stored like text '[{"x":1, "y":1} ...]'

in controller I have

```
/**
 * Matches /polygon exactly
 *
 * @Route("/", name="polygon_list")
 * @Method("GET")
 *
 * @Rest\Get("/")
 *
 */
public function listAction()
{
    return $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Polygon')
        ->findAll();
}
```

so I'm getting 
ReflectionProperty::getValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given

in ...vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/PropertyMetadata.php:51

If it were only to get result, it could be solved by using virtual property

```
/**
 * @JMS\Exclude
 */
private $points;

/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty
 * @JMS\Type("array<MyBundle\Model\Point>")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("points")
 * @JMS\Groups({"common"})
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getMyPoints() {
    return [new Point(), new Point()]
}
```

But I need to receive this points as JSON from POST so the only way I found so far is Doctrine custom type similar to 
https://github.com/sonata-project/sonata-doctrine-extensions

with only difference that in convertToPHPValue method I'm addind additional typecast to receive objects instead of assoc array:

```
// pass my [{"x":1, "y":1} ...]
public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
       return array_map(function($a){ return (object)$a;}, json_decode($value));
    }
```

**Is there is a more clean solution, without adding custom Doctrine serialization?**

if only this 
...vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/PropertyMetadata.php:51
had

```
return $this->reflection->getValue((object)$obj);
```

but it's

```
return $this->reflection->getValue($obj); // :(
```

Comment: if the doctrine fields is a json_array why you don't try to dump as string for jmsserializer?

Comment: you can find a discussion [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/431) about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in using @JMS\Type at all

```
    class Polygon {
         /**
          * @ORM\Column(name="polygon", type="json_array")
          */
          private $points;

          public function getPoints() { return $this->points;}
          public function setPoints($points) {
               $this->points = $points;
               return $this;
          }
          /***/
    }
```

Works just fine, thanks @Matteo for pointing out that I'm complicating a things :)

Comment: The downvote here is probably because you posted some bogus text and then edited within the grace window.  It's possible that the downvoter will notice and retract their downvote, but there's really no clean way back.  I suppose all you can do is take note for the future to not do that.